# java.lang.IllegalStateException: in FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Getting crash only on playstore but not on testing in real time

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.i.a (FragmentManager.java:1891)
  at android.support.v4.app.b.g (BackStackRecord.java:760)
  at android.support.v4.app.i.b (FragmentManager.java:2596)
  at android.support.v4.app.i.a (FragmentManager.java:2383)
  at android.support.v4.app.i.b (FragmentManager.java:2338)
  at android.support.v4.app.i.g (FragmentManager.java:2245)
  at android.support.v4.app.i$1.run (FragmentManager.java:703)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:746)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: There might be crashed because of _FragmentTransaction_ . Post more stacktrace.

Comment: i get this report only on play store.

Comment: Share line number at which it crash.

Comment: play store not mention any thing about the crash line i just post the crash code exact as i received in play store

Comment: Check it proper. There is log in Crash report.

Comment: i added my play store crash screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185704/discussion-between-sarath-kumar-and-piyush).